# System::Threading::Timer, make it running at the same time as form

Tags: multithreading, winforms, timer, c++-cli

I couldn't find any really simple example on how to create a threaded timer to run along my form.
The goal of my application is simple, I just want it to check the ping and update the label. I tried the WindowsForms::Timer, but it runs on the same thread as UI, so using UI, while constantly refreshing is not an option.

Edit:
So my question is, how can I create a function that runs independently to my form, and changes the label text, in the way that my UI is responsive. I've already tried understanding the Threading:::Timer MSDN Page, but I couldn't really understand how it works, searched internet for an easy eaxample/implementation, but to no avail.

```
// WindowsFormApplication1.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace WindowsFormApplication1;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

and additionally my form1, with WindowsForms::Timer :

```
#include "icmpsendecho2.h"
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
#pragma once

namespace WindowsFormApplication1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
...
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    //System::String^ managed = "test";
    //std::string unmanaged = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(managed);

    double ping1 = pinger(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(Adress1->Text));
    double ping2 = pinger(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(Adress2->Text));
    PingShow1->Text= System::Convert::ToString(ping1);
    PingShow2->Text = System::Convert::ToString(ping2);
    if (ping1 > 250)
        PingShow1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
    if (ping1 > 80)
        PingShow1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Yellow;
    if (ping1 == -1)
        PingShow1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Violet;
    else
        PingShow1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Green;

    if (ping2 > 250)
        PingShow2->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
    if (ping2 > 80)
        PingShow2->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Yellow;
    if(ping2==-1)
        PingShow2->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Violet;
    else
        PingShow2->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Green;

}
};
}
```

Any help would be apreciated, thanks!

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried? How did your try work (or not work)? Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Then also [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: //but it runs on the same thread as UI// 
A small correction in your understanding, Timer and UI will always have dedicated thread running separately.

Comment: Just edited it, added more explanations of what I want to achieve, also pasted the whole code, for better understanding of my problem. ("icmpsendecho2.h" has an old function double pinger(std::string) that I wrote with some help to ping an adress, it is in C, so had to convert managed string to unmanaged.)